# Swift Memory management in the class

Tags: swift, memory-management

I have a case when I do not understand if `A` object will be released or not.This is connected with function `func b` of class `A` that take as parameter function.

This is simple representation of the problem:

```
class A {

    func a() {

    }

    func b(_: ()->()) {

    }

    func doThm() {
        b(a)
    }
}



var a = A()
a.doThm()
```

Comment: Function `b` doesn't take function as parameter, it takes value of `Void`/`()`/`Unit` type.

Comment: Sorry, not exactly clear what do you ask?  The variable `a` holds a strong reference to the object, so it's not going to be released (regardless of the method that takes a closure as an argument).

Comment: I edit my question. sorry it was wrong example

Comment: And for updated code: as long as `b` is not accepting function as [`@escaping`](https://cocoacasts.com/what-do-escaping-and-noescaping-mean-in-swift-3/) there shouldn't be any ownership cycles and `A`-object won't stuck in memory.

Comment: I edit my problem so that question is a bit more clear.

Comment: Please don't change your original question to something else—otherwise existing answers become out of sync. If you're still confused please just post a new question. But it looks like you got the hang of it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your class `A` has no stored properties there can be no retain cycle.

*Calling* a function (closure) does not create retain cycles. *Storing* the closure might.

Comment: You are right I test this. I receive retina circle only when I save closer in the variable. But could you please explain why Storing the closure might do retain circle ?

Comment: * ret**ain** cycle, and read [this](http://www.thomashanning.com/retain-cycles-weak-unowned-swift/)